# Delay for a certain time before going into next intent in runnable

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent

I am now trying to delay for a certain time before going to the next intent. I tried with postdelayed method but nothing works.

```js
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

runInBackground(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(condition has met){
                        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            Intent i=new Intent(DetectorActivity.this,Main4Activity.class);
                                            startActivity(i);
                                            finish();

                                        }
                                    };
                                    mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000000);
                        }
               
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `Runnable` but you're just running internal one by using `postDelayed()`.
You should run the first one too.
like this

```
runInBackground(new Runnable() {
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                }.run());
```